# Perl find duplicates in first column and convert to unique auto incremented value

Tags: perl

I have a tab delimited text file (test.txt) that looks like the following:

```
Steve   ran 100 200 300
Steve   sit 50  30  20
Steve   steal   40  60  70
Bill    ran 10  20  90
Bill    get 14  15  30
John    up  34  38  29
John    ran 10  40  60
John    down    60  70  80
John    yep 40  69  80
```

I need to replace the duplicate values in column 1 with a unique identifier, i.e. Steve => Name_1, Bill => Name_2, John => Name_3, etc.  The order of the text file is important, so read line by line?  Here's what I have so far...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, "<", 'test.txt';
while (<$fh>) {
    my @row = split(/\s+/,$_);
    print "$row[0]\t$row[1]\t$row[2]\t$row[3]\t$row[4]\n";  
    }

close $fh;
exit;
```

My desired output would be:

```
Name_1   ran 100 200 300
Name_1   sit 50  30  20
Name_1   steal   40  60  70
Name_2   ran 10  20  90
Name_2   get 14  15  30
Name_3   up  34  38  29
Name_3   ran 10  40  60
Name_3   down    60  70  80
Name_3   yep 40  69  80
```

Comment: How big is your file? How many different names do you expect? Are all instances of the same name on consecutive lines, as they are in your example data?

Comment: If it is tab delimited file you can split like this `split(/\t/,$_);`

Comment: The text input will be somewhere around 500 lines.  Yes, the duplicated value in column 1 will be listed consecutively (anywhere from 5 to 30 times) and then it will change to a different value, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever duplicates need to be removed, using a hash is often a good approach.

In this case, you need to declare the hash outside the `while` loop, then check each name to see if it already exists in the hash.  If it does, use the value from the has, otherwise create a new key, and store the value you want.

Something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, "<", 'test.txt';
my %names;
my $count;
while (<$fh>) {
    my @row = split(/\s+/,$_);
    if (not exists $names{$row[0]}) {
        $names{$row[0]} = "Name_" . ++$count;
    }
    print "$names{$row[0]}\t$row[1]\t$row[2]\t$row[3]\t$row[4]\n";  
}

close $fh;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do as you ask. It keeps a hash `%names` that records what the replacement name should be for each original value. The number `$n` keeps track of the next number to be assigned to a newly-occurring name

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my %names;
my $n;

open my $fh, '<', 'test.txt';
while ( <$fh> ) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /\t/;
  $fields[0] = $names{$fields[0]} //= 'Name_'.++$n;
  say join "\t", @fields;
}
```

**output**

```
Name_1  ran 100 200 300
Name_1  sit 50  30  20
Name_1  steal 40  60  70
Name_2  ran 10  20  90
Name_2  get 14  15  30
Name_3  up  34  38  29
Name_3  ran 10  40  60
Name_3  down  60  70  80
Name_3  yep 40  69  80
```